# Is it possible to extend notes and also shift the 2nd 3rd etc notes offset from the first note?

Tags: ableton-live

[image]Is it possible to extend a set of notes (or a whole piece) while also updating its offset from the first selected note? For example, when I select 2 notes 1/4 apart and drag to scale them to 1/2 notes size I want to see 2 x 1/2 notes next to each other (not 1 x 1/4 and 1 x 1/2). This is a little tricky to explain but let me know if you need another example or picture illustration of what I mean.

Regards, Tom

Comment: I think i have seen how this could be done. But i am not sure if it was with ableton or some other DAW. Did you try to hold some keys on your keyboard while dragging the last note with your mouse? Maybe something like 'alt', 'control', 'shift' or some combination.

Comment: Otherwise this is probably something the support of ableton could help you with.

Comment: Hi @Olli. I tried every key combination I could think of and did a lot of googling without any luck! I'll try to get in touch with the support team

Answer (score 2):

hey i figured this out.

you use time stretch in the top of the midi roll once you've selected the notes. its the little blue bar that appears with a marker on it. you move that marker

[image]